# Display custom links above an array collection using Jbuilder

Tags: json, api, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jbuilder

I have a custom JSON response in which I display a collection of 15 posts along with related data like comments etc., as part of an API call. I am displaying the entire collection using [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) .

```
json.array!(@posts) do |post|
  ..
  ..
end
```

I want to display pagination links above the response of the 15 posts, in order to get the next set of posts with the appropriate next set of next page and prev page pagination links. In my abc.json.jbuilder file if I try doing it as per the below code, I don't get links to the next and prev page as part of my JSON response.

```
json.pagination_links do
  json.set!(:next_page_link,"#{@next_page_link}")   
  json.set!(:prev_page_link,"#{@prev_page_link}")   
end

json.array!(@posts) do |post|
  ..
  ..
end
```

The only response, that I get is the array which has a collection of posts. Which looks like below:-

```
[
 -{post1}
 -{post2}
 -..
]
```

I guess there is something that I might be missing. Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the [answer](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/110#issuecomment-14945092), credits to [Pavel Pravosud](https://github.com/rwz) for the support